# Set spacing in GraphicsRow and GraphicsColumn equal to zero

Tags: graphics

How it is possible to set spacing in GraphicsRow and GraphicsColumn equal zero?

```
GraphicsRow[{
  GraphicsColumn[
   {Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 35], 
    Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 35]}, Spacings -> 0
 ],
 GraphicsColumn[
  {Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 35], 
   Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 35]}, Spacings -> 0
 ]}, Spacings -> 0
]
```

gives this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `options1` for  `Graphics` and `options2` for `GraphicsRow` and for`GraphicsColumn` where

```
options1 = Sequence[ImageSize -> 35, ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0];
options2 = Sequence[Spacings -> 0, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}];

GraphicsRow[{GraphicsColumn[{Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[]}, options1],
    Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[]}, options1]}, options2],
  GraphicsColumn[{Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[]}, options1],
    Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[]}, options1]}, options2]}, options2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Use negative numbers for spacings:

```
GraphicsRow[{GraphicsColumn[{Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[]}, 
     ImageSize -> 35], 
    Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 35]}, Spacings -> -2], 
  GraphicsColumn[{Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 35], 
    Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 35]}, 
   Spacings -> -2]}, Spacings -> -18]
```

[image]

The numbers are relative to the default spacing, so positive is further apart and negative is closer together.