# Two png images aligned in one column with vertical spacing zero and left aligned

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

I have the following two png images which I want to left-align in one column with zero vertical spacing, retaining their original size (which is for both the same, `1600 x 542 pixels`}):

I found the following [question/answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136843/set-spacing-in-graphicsrow-and-graphicscolumn-equal-to-zero) but don't know how to use it for my case.

png1:

[image]

png2:

[image]

If I try the following

```
GraphicsColumn[{png1, png2}, Left, 0]
```

the result

[image]

I would like to have a vertical spacing of zero and the width/height of the images in the column should be the same as the original have.

How can I do that?

Comment: does `Style[Column[{png1, png2}, Spacings -> 0], ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr: Thank you very much for the solution … but what for  is `GraphicsColumn` good, if it can not be used for this problem.

Comment: mrz,  how about `Style[GraphicsColumn[{png1, png2}, Spacings -> 0, 
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
  ItemAspectRatio -> 1/(Divide @@ ImageDimensions[png1])], 
 ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GraphicsColumn[{png1, png2}, 
 Spacings -> 0, 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
 ItemAspectRatio -> 1/(Divide @@ ImageDimensions[png1])]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect … Ich had only to add at the end `ImageSize -> Full`, to keep the size as in the originals.